# SQL Server if exist update else insert

Tags: sql-server

The below query not checking update statement always insert only , where i am doing the wrong in the below code.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UpdateData]
  @JobOrder varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
      --DECLARE @UPDATING INT
      IF EXISTS(SELECT  1  FROM [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE JobOrder=@JobOrder ORDER BY JobStatus DESC) 

      BEGIN
          UPDATE [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] 
          SET 
          RepairComment = (SELECT Top 1 Status_Comment FROM LOCALDB.dbo.LOCALTABLE Where REPAIRNO=@JobOrder Order By TRACKINGID desc),
          Amount = (SELECT Top 1 LABOR_AMT+PARTS_AMT As Amount FROM LOCALDB.dbo.LOCALTABLE Where REPAIRNO=@JobOrder Order By TRACKINGID desc),
          JobStatus = (SELECT Top 1 Job_Status FROM LOCALDB.dbo.LOCALTABLE Where REPAIRNO=@JobOrder Order By TRACKINGID desc)
          WHERE JobOrder=@JobOrder
      END
         ELSE BEGIN

               INSERT INTO [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE](JobOrder,RepairComment,JobStatus,Branch,Customer,
               Contact,Technician,ReceiptDate,Complaint,Amount,Warranty,ServiceType)
               (
                Select Top 1
                JT.REPAIRNO,JT.StatusComment,JT.JobStatus,
                SJ.MAINSC,SJ.CUSTOMER + ' ' + SJ.CUSTOMERLAST AS FullName,SJ.Tel,SJ.ENGINEER,SJ.RECEIPTDATE,
                SJ.DEFECTDESC,SJ.LABOR_AMT+PARTS_AMT As Amount,SJ.WARRANTY,SJ.SERVICETYPE
                FROM
                LOCALDB1 SJ
                INNER JOIN LOCALDB2 JT ON
                JT.REPAIRNO=SJ.REPAIRNO
                WHERE JT.REPAIRNO=SJ.REPAIRNO)
          END
END
```

trying to update the data to remoteserver from localdb.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that proc - it should behave as you expect. EXCEPT for the ORDER BY in your exists - why is that there? It doesn't make any different the result of your EXISTS clause. What datatype is the column `JobOrder`? If you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE JobOrder =x` before and after you run the proc (for x), are the rows the same or different?

Comment: You could also rewrite that to not need to use the `IF` at all and that might be easier to debug. You basically put add to your `where` on your insert and update like this: `WHERE JT.REPAIRNO=SJ.REPAIRNO AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1  FROM [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE JobOrder=@JobOrder)`

Comment: thats true i just to search the data with orderby it was not there i want to see which one is last update to remote. JobOrder is varchar. i dont get what is run count(before and after)?

Comment: By count, I mean run a count just to confirm that you _really_ inserted a record. Count the records matching the JobOrder before and after you run your proc just to confirm.

Comment: Wait a sec... when you insert you are not actually inserting the joborder in. Is that the intention? You are inserting `REPAIRNO` into the job order field. So you'll never get a new record with your joborder in it so it will happily just keep inserting records. You don't use JobOrder at all in your insert

Comment: yes , it is inserting all the data. i am trying to catch up this point " WHERE JT.REPAIRNO=SJ.REPAIRNO AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE JobOrder=@JobOrder) " ?

Comment: JobOrder and RepairNo are same data.

Comment: They might be the same data but in your second select you aren't filtering on it. You're taking the first random record from the table which probably doesn't match `@JobOrder` at all ad your inserting it across. I'm guessing you need to change `WHERE JT.REPAIRNO=SJ.REPAIRNO` to `WHERE JT.REPAIRNO = @JobOrder` but I can't be sure because I don't know what your tables look like and I don't know what you're trying to do

Comment: Nick.McDermaid , i guess thats make working. still updating, so far no duplicate. you made my day. thanks nick. really thanks.

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of your proc

```
WHERE JT.REPAIRNO=SJ.REPAIRNO
```

Does not select any particular job number. It just picks a random record from the source and inserts it.

Change it to this:

```
WHERE JT.REPAIRNO=@JobOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug this simply put in a valid @JobOrder value and execute the code Highlighting from the "SELECT *" after the second dash commenting out the line......execute the sql and make sure the results are correct

```
     BEGIN
         UPDATE [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] 
         SET
             RepairComment = lc.Status_Comment,
             Amount = lc.Amount,
             JobStatus = lc.Job_Status
        --SELECT *
           FROM [ADDLINKSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE] as t1
         INNER JOIN (SELECT top 1 Status_Comment
                                 ,LABOR_AMT+PARTS_AMT As Amount
                                 ,Job_Status
                            FROM LOCALDB.dbo.LOCALTABLE 
                         Where REPAIRNO=@JobOrder 
                            Order By TRACKINGID desc) as lc
            ON t1.JobOrder=lc.REPAIRNO
        WHERE t1.JobOrder=@JobOrder
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than going this way you get count of your result and check if count >0 than update else you can insert

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO l_cnt
  FROM table

IF( l_cnt > 0 )
THEN
  Update
END IF;
```

Comment: count has to count all the rows. EXISTS does not. EXISTS is better

Comment: ... and thats Oracle syntax!